# EMRserverless is allocating half of the memory to the executors than what we actually define in spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

When I define an spark's executor's memory to 12gb, it actually allocates almost half of it like 6.7gb.

Tried setting 20gb as well, then it allocates close to 11gb, half of it.

I have defined sufficient application limits like cores, memory and disk space but am facing this strange issue.

It's just not with server less EMR, same issue is there with regular EMR too

Job is submitted by airflow dags as follows:

```
job_task = EmrServerlessStartJobOperator(
            task_id=dag_id,
            application_id=emrAppId,
            execution_role_arn=roleId,
            execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=8),
            config={"name": dag_id,"executionTimeoutMinutes": 3600},
            job_driver={
                "sparkSubmit": {
                    "entryPoint": configuration['S3_DAGS_HDFS_JARS_PATH']+"/app-jobs.jar",
                    "entryPointArguments": job_args,
                    "sparkSubmitParameters": "--class com.edifecs.em.cloud.ecf.MyMainClass"+
                    " --conf spark.jars=configuration['S3_DAGS_HDFS_JARS_PATH']+"/hudi/hudi-utilities-bundle_*.jar" +
                    " --executor-cores=4" +
                    " --conf spark.driver.cores=4"+ 
                    " --conf spark.executor.memory=12G" + 
                    " --conf spark.driver.memory=8G"+ 
                    " --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=4"+ 
                    " --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=2"+ 
                    " --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=30"
                }
            }
```

My serverless application limits are:
Vcpus=130
Maximum memory: 450Gb
Disk: 650Gb

Any specific reason?

Comment: Could you please share your `aws emr-serverless create-application`, `aws emr-serverless start-job-run` commands and how you checked the actual allocated resources?

Comment: @LioniaVasilev I have edited my question with more details. I submit job from airflow dag and I check resources on job's spark UI > executor section > Executor memory allocated to each executor column

Comment: The memory shown in the Spark UI is different than the memory allocated for the executor, it's the memory available for storage (a fraction of the total memory). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47014697/5141922